# Using alert.accept() multiple times does not function properly

Tags: python, automated-tests, splinter

Hi I am currently new to being a Automated QA (in `Splinter`) tester using Python, What I want to do is to test a payment page to see if there are prompts if the required fields are empty and log it into the notepad.

My problem is that when I use `alert.accept()` twice it does not run the second time around.

For example:
The first prompt is expected to say "Transaction Type input is trapped" and then I use `alert.accept()` to close the prompt. But the second time around it does not work the prompt just stays where it is and does not automatically click the ok button when I use `alert.accept()`. Why is this? Is there a rule i'm missing when i'm using two alerts at the same time?

```
def checkTrappings():   
    logUtb(f, 'Checking if Transaction type is trapped, making payment with Transaction type as empty')
    browser.find_by_id('submitBtn').first.click()
    alert = browser.get_alert()
    x = str(alert.text) 
    if x == 'Transaction Type is required.':
        logUtb(f, 'Transaction Type input is trapped')
    alert.accept()  
    logUtb(f, "")

    logUtb(f, 'Checking if email is a valid email')
    browser.select('tranType','A')
    browser.find_by_id('submitBtn').first.click()
    alert = browser.get_alert()
    x = str(alert.text)
    if x == 'Please enter a valid email address.':
        logUtb(f, 'Proper email format is trapped')

    alert.accept()  
    logUtb(f, "")

    browser.find_by_id('submitBtn').first.click()
    alert = browser.get_alert()
    x = str(alert.text)
```

`logUtb` by the way is my function where I log the report to the notepad

```
    def logUtb(fl, strx):
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  fl.write(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') + " - " + strx + "\n");
  return;
```

The library i'm using is splinter

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: the library i'm using is splinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making two functions to check different fields but I i'm not sure why it worked and I also don't like it , why make two functions when you can create one with the same functionality.

```
def checkTrapTransaction(): 
    try:
        logUtb(f, 'Checking if Transaction type is trapped, making payment with Transaction type as empty')
        browser.find_by_id('submitBtn').first.click()
        alert = browser.get_alert()
        x = str(alert.text) 
        if x == 'Transaction Type is required.':
            logUtb(f, 'Transaction Type input is trapped')
        alert.accept()  
        logUtb(f, "")

    except:
        logUtbE(f, "Exception: Please recheck your code")

def checkTrapEmail():
    try:
        logUtb(f, 'Checking if email is a valid email')
        browser.select('tranType','A')
        browser.find_by_id('submitBtn').first.click()
        alert = browser.get_alert()
        x = str(alert.text)
        if x == 'Please enter a valid email address.':
            logUtb(f, 'Proper email format is trapped')

        alert.accept()  
        logUtb(f, "")

    except:
        logUtbE(f, "Exception: Please recheck your code")
```

If you guys have other solutions to this problem, i'm open to suggestions as I don't like the fix I just made. Thanks